# Who has written Bhagvat Geeta?

Tags: krishna, bhagavad-gita, arjuna

It is said that Bhagvat Geeta was told by Shri Krishna to Arjuna. And there were total 4 people involved in it Shri Krishna, Arjuna, Sanjay and Dhritrashtra.

Shri Krishna was telling Bhagvat Geeta to Arjuna. Sanjay was narrating everything to Dhritrashtra in kurukshtra war.

My Question is who was writing all of the shlok/conversation of Shri Krishna and Arjuna.

As we know that Mahabharata was narrated by Mahrashi Vyas and written by Lord Ganpati.

**Who wrote Bhagvat Geeta when Shri Krishna was narrating it to Arjuna?**

Comment: you answered your question. Vyasa saw all the events through his mind, and narrated it to Ganesha who was the scribe.

Comment: It is thoughts (or gyan) of Lord Vishnu himself. He first give knowledge of Geeta to God Sun. Then God Sun spread this knowledge. But later this knowledge started to vanish from earth. So to spread this knowledge on earth again, Lord Vishnu gave this knowledge to the people of Earth himself (in his 8th incarnation) by making Arjuna as media. Later his thoughts being wrote by many writers in different books and in different time. First writer was Ganesha and Vayas. But source of this knowledge is Lord Vishnu.

Comment: And one more thing, There was not only 4 people who hear Bhagwat Geeta from Krishna. There was also 5th person who was present there in invisible (adrishya) form. And that person was Lord Hanuman. Who joined Mahabharat war on order of Lord krishna. He stayed in Mahabharata war during all time in invisible form. And he also hear everything from Lord krishna and also saw Virat Swaroop of Lord Krishna, like Arjuna saw.

Comment: Bhagavat Gita is a part of the Itihasa called Mahabharatha and which was composed by Maharshi Vyasa.

Comment: @iammilind You posts same duplicate comment on almost every post But Most of them were not duplicate. So IMHO it would be better if you use keywords like  **Related or Relevant question** instead of **Possible duplicate of**. Because most of your suggested are not duplicate but instead they were relevant. Besides using **duplicate** word unnecessary everywhere is kinda harsh behavior which might hurt OP a little. The post which are not exact duplicate AND which are **not giving answer of OP's question**, those posts can't be called as duplicate but they should be called relevant.

Comment: @Rishabh, it's always good to suggest posts which are **Possible Duplicate**s. It's less likely to get exact duplicates in most cases. You may refer about "borderline duplicate" in the [1st point of this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/10844/163449). For the users other than diamond Mods, at least 5 votes are required to close a Qn. If the other users don't agree, then my 1 vote won't harm. If you felt hurt, when I suggested a dupe, then sorry about that. As you already said, that I do it for many posts, so it's not to offend anyone. This Qn is already answered in the linked Qn-s.

Comment: Much of Bhagavad-gītā we know today is a huge interpolation, see [this](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/18876/2995) and [this](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/18897/2995) answer. So your question is a rather confusing one :P

Comment: @Rishabh Pandya used the related and didn't post the duplicate comment because he is a moderator. He he votes, it will be closed. Even if any normal user like us votes to close, it doesn't harm because it says *Possible duplicate* not exact duplicate. It is possible or not possible. It is an automated comment. Users don't type it.

Comment: @ram I didn't know that Bhagwat Geet is part of Mahabharat.

Comment: How this question is Duplicate I don't understand

Comment: @sv. What is confusing in this question.

Comment: @PraveenGaikwad It's confusing because MB had several authors. BG being part of MB could have several authors too. "As we know that Mahabharata was narrated by Maharshi Vyasa and written by Lord Ganapati" - your premise is false, check the Debroy tr. of Mahabharata based on the latest BORI critical edition [here](http://www.amazon.in/Mahabharata-1-Bibek-Debroy/dp/0143425145). See [this extract](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uPTK0.jpg).

Comment: Don't listen to @sv, he follows some random BORI edition which thinks everything that is supernatural is interpolated. Bhagavad Gita has many Bhashyas (commentaries) by acharyas (Adi Shankara, Madhwa) - read that to get what is authentic. BORI edition edited by some indian guy educated in Britain, married english woman, so we cannot expect him to give us full truth.

Comment: I found this to be an interesting question to which I did not know that answer. It was closed as a duplicate without pointing out which question it duplicates. This leads future readers without the answer. What a waste of opportunity to teach others who are interested.