# Shri Krushna's revelation of his real identity

Tags: krishna, brahman, maya

Shri Krushna had made many others understand "who is he" -- *Shri Narayana* himself, supreme Brahman. 
But after revealing his real identity, he made them forget the revelation by using "*Maya*", the illusive power.

Reason maybe "the time was yet not right and those people had to yet go through their sufferings (*prarabdha*)".
Examples being *Yashoda, Devaki, Vasudev, Sudama*, etc.
For Yashoda, it's mentioned in [SB 10.8](https://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/10/8)

But, to some others such as *Arjuna, Bheeshma, Kunti, Akroor, Muchukunda*, he didn't make them forget the truth.
These people always knew the truth.

What might be the reason?

Comment: No, Krishna didn't made them (Yashoda, Devaki, Vasudev, Sudama) forget who is he. Can you please add any reference for concluding that Krishna made them forget?

Comment: I have heard it through a "satsang". Let me try to find a concrete ref in 'Bhagwat'. BTW, how did you come to the conclusion that he didn't make them forget? Till we find (or till we don't find after searching) the reference, both possibilities stand equal chance :-)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/85182/discussion-on-question-by-vineet-shri-krushnas-revelation-of-his-real-identity).

Comment: For Yashoda, it's mentioned in [SB 10.8](https://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/10/8). You can add that in ur Q to clearify comments ...bdw u hv answered Ur q by urself **"The reason being that the time was yet not right"**...then what else u r looking for?

Comment: @YDS , Thanks for the reference of Yashoda Maiyya. Reg your 2nd point in comment, I had just expressed my opinion that "The reason being that the time was yet not right". But I do not know any reference in script. That's why I asked the Q.

Comment: @KrishnaShweta Yes, Lord Krishna sometimes makes his devotees, who are very advanced and completely surrendered souls to him, to forget that he is the Supreme Lord and sometimes he makes them to be like ordinary ignorants. See at the above link in chat how RaRa explained Arjuna's behavior. See also how I explained Arjuna's ignorance in my comments in conversation with RakeshJoshi below answer by YDS at https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/29615/2790

Comment: @brahma Yes, you and OP are correct in saying that Lord Krishna made them forget. Just read exact verses in SB-10.44 and 45.

Comment: @Krishna Can you specify exactly the verse numbers on what you said?

Comment: @brahma Actually it starts from SB-10.44.51 but the exact verse which talks about maya is in SB-10.45.1-2